# (Java) add list of lists to ArrayList<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a list of integer lists that I have initialized.

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList();
```

I also have some data that I need to append to this list.

```
list = [[1,5,9], [3,5,7], [1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9], [1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
```

**EDIT:**
I understand that this is not a legal way to express a list of lists in java (python background) but I do not know how to do so in Java.

What would be the best way to append this data to a list of lists in Java?

Comment: How is that data represented?

Comment: right now just like the list variable above, I come from a python background so the list of lists is there, i dont know how to express it in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(1,5,9),
    Arrays.asList(3,5,7),
    Arrays.asList(1,4,7),
    Arrays.asList(2,5,8),
    Arrays.asList(3,6,9),
    Arrays.asList(1,2,3),
    Arrays.asList(4,5,6),
    Arrays.asList(7,8,9)
);
```

if it is okay that the lists can’t change their size once they’ve been created.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would probably be to use [`Arrays#asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
List<List<Integer>> list = 
    Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 9),
                  Arrays.asList(3, 5, 7),
                  /* etc... */
                 );
```

**EDIT:**

If you're using Java 9 or above, you could also use the slightly more elegant [`List#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-):

```
List<List<Integer>> list = 
    List.of(List.of(1, 5, 9),
            List.of(3, 5, 7),
            /* etc... */
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using java-8 :

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = Stream
            .of(Arrays.asList(1, 5, 9), Arrays.asList(3, 5, 7), Arrays.asList(1, 4, 7), 
                Arrays.asList(2, 5, 8), Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9), Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), 
                Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6), Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```